# ado.net mvc3 multiple models and single views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have 3 entities: `sender` `receiver` and `parcel`. I want to update it from one view, is there any link. I'm using ADO.NET for models and using database first approach. Is there any method to get all the models in one view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create viewmodel that "contains" those 3 entities.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Sender Sender {get; set}
    public Receiver Receive {get; set;}
    public Parcel Parcel {get; set;}
}
```

of course this is the simplest solution.

Comment: @MuhammadNauman, While this solution works, you would be better off creating a flattened ViewModel, that is a composite of the values you need in your view, as opposed to passing all of the data entities to the view.

Comment: i have do it but when I'm trying to add controller of it the its gives error message.

Comment: 1) unable to retrieve the meta data of the new created model if you have any link of video with ADO.NET datafirst approach please share it

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/data/gg702905 - but you should try use google next time :)